# Deleting comments while reviewing Close Votes

Tags: bug, review, moderator-tools, comment-voting

Normally, moderators can delete comments at will.
An odd exception is while reviewing the Close Votes queue,
where the delete link next to comments is missing.
So if I want to clean up some comments,
I'm forced to open the question in a new tab and do it there.
This happens a lot,
and it would be a lot easier if I could clean up comments at the same time as reviewing close votes.

As this behavior is inconsistent with the rest of the site,
I suspect this is unintentional, a bug.

Can you please make it possible for moderators to delete comments while reviewing the Close Votes queue?

Comment: On what site @janos?

Comment: Does this also happen to you in the Reopen votes queue? I was unable to delete (my own) comment there.